# Converting hex string (delimited with colons) to decimal array: Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am extracting some data form a file, including strings like:

```
n ={[1,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:64  
    [2,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:69
    [3,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:69
    [4,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:69
   }
```

I need to change the '0' to '00', and the '7' to '07'. Then use the function `hex2dec` to convert it into decimal numbers.

I'm using the following code:

```
r=strrep(0:7:80:bc:eb:69 , ':', ''); 
m= hex2dec(r)
```

Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split **each string** on `:` using [`strsplit`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html). That gives a cell array of strings (char vectors) that you can directly pass to `hex2dec`; no need for zero-padding:

```
n = {'0:7:80:bc:eb:64';
     '0:7:80:bc:eb:69';
     '0:7:80:bc:eb:69';
     '0:7:80:bc:eb:69'}; % data: cell array of strings
k = 1; % select one cell
t = strsplit(n{k}, ':');
result = hex2dec(t);
```

This gives

```
t =
    '0'    '7'    '80'    'bc'    'eb'    '64'

result =
     0
     7
   128
   188
   235
   100
```

---

To get the numbers from **all strings** as a matrix, join the strings of the cell array using [`strjoin`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html), apply the above, and then apply [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
n = {'0:7:80:bc:eb:64';
     '0:7:80:bc:eb:69';
     '0:7:80:bc:eb:69';
     '0:7:80:bc:eb:69'}; % data: cell array of strings
nj = strjoin(n, ':');
t = strsplit(nj, ':');
result = hex2dec(t);
result = reshape(result, [], numel(n)).';
```

This gives

```
result =
     0     7   128   188   235   100
     0     7   128   188   235   105
     0     7   128   188   235   105
     0     7   128   188   235   105
```

Comment: When I do it, a message error appear: error: strsplit: S and DEL must be string values. I think this is because the format of the file i extract doesn't match.. Here is the file extracted: n =
{
  [1,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:64
  [2,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:69
  [3,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:69
  [4,1] = 0:7:80:bc:eb:69
}

Comment: @Mbdt Did you try replacing `s` with `n{1}`?

Comment: @beaker Good idea. I hadn't seen the updated question. Edited

Comment: Thanks it works!! and is there a function allowing me to make the sum of these values ? @LuisMendo

Comment: The sum of the `result` vector? Use `sum(result)`

Comment: @LuisMendo but if i want to get the number of all string but string by string? i have tried to change the parameter ` : ` by `\n`  of `strjoin` to have line by line but then it doesn't count every element.. and for some line for `result` i get `Nan`

Comment: @Mbdt You need to be more precise. Do all strings contain 6 numbers? Do you want a 6xN or an Nx6 matrix as result?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes all strings contain 6 numbers. As result, the best would be Nx6 with N= 4 because there are 4 line in the cell array. And then use the function `hex2dec` as above for every line of the new matrix.

Answer (score 3):

strsplit and hex2dec work fine as the above answer suggested. I am providing a simpler and faster solution by sscanf:

```
n = {'0:7:80:bc:eb:64';
 '0:7:80:bc:eb:69';
 '0:7:80:bc:eb:69';
 '0:7:80:bc:eb:69'}; % data: cell array of strings

t = sscanf(n{1}, '%x:')'

t =

 0     7   128   188   235   100
```